What kind of equations is needed to solve this kind of problem?
Imagine that I have the following situation, it is raining with different intensity along ($x$-coordinate) and a man is holding a bucket and is walking with varying velocity $v(x)$, how do I find the total volume of the water at the end of his path?

edit: the man can also go back and forth? I guess I should have written v(t) instead.

If $r(x)$ is the rate at which rain is falling at location (in volume/second), and the man is near that point for a time $dt$, then the bucket will accumulate $r \, dt$ of water.  If the man is walking at a speed $v(x)$, then the time for him to pass through a small interval $dx$ near the point $x$ is $dx = v \, dt$.
Combining these two means that the water accumulated when the man moves from $x$ to $x + dx$ is $[r(x)/v(x)] \, dx$.  You would then need to integrate this quantity over the path.

I disagree with your solution. In the frame moving with the man, the rain does not fall vertically. You need to use the flux of drops through the surface of the bucket to calculate the amount of water received.

What will happen if the man goes back and forth? this would mean that at the point when the change of direction occurs, the speed would be zero. I guess I should have written v(t) instead

@Shaktyai:  You're right that the raindrops' velocity $\vec{v}$ in the man's reference frame is not vertical.  But assuming the bucket is held level at all times, then only the vertical component of this velocity matters, since the flux through a surface is going to be proportional to $\vec{A} \cdot \vec{v}$ and $\vec{A}$ is vertical.  And assuming the man is only moving horizontally, the vertical component of the raindrops' velocity is the same in both frames.

@FarAt If you know $v(t)$ instead, integrate it to find $x(t)$, and then integrate $\int r(x(t)) , dt$ to find the accumulation.
